# ruby split lines from files while iterating each line

Tags: ruby

I have a log fine which contains status of my application related components and when I iterated that log file by each line I need to split all the lines which relies between to lines.

For example I have below log file,

```
- Component 1 Check
- Nodes check
  * status of sub string 1
  * status of sub string 2 
- Jakarta component check
```

so in the above example, I need to split the lines between "`- Nodes`" and "`- Jakarta`"

Comment: What do you mean, "split the lines"?

Comment: I meant to say while iterating each line just put them into different variable or hash something like that. Basically I am planning to segregate them

Comment: yeaaah, so, while iterating line by line, do put them in separate variables or a hash or something. What's the question, again? (I'm assuming you already know how to iterate line by line)

Comment: Yeah I knew how to iterate line by line, but my query is how to get lines only between particular matched string lines.

Comment: Iterate until you see `"- Nodes"`. From then on, put all lines into a special hash. Do that until you see `"- Jakarta"`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev special hashes were introduced in 2.3 only.

Comment: @mudasobwa: huh, what special hashes? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev your previous comment here stated “iterate, blah-blah, then _put all lines into **a special hash**_.”

Comment: @mudasobwa: yes, but there were no special hashes in 2.3. If that was a joke, I didn't get it :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev As we now can see it was an unsuccessful attempt to joke :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interesting solution with Enumerators :

```
middle_lines = File.open('data.txt') do |file|
  every_line             = file.each_line
  every_line_til_Jakarta = every_line.take_while { |line| !line.include?('Jakarta') }
  every_line_after_nodes = every_line_til_Jakarta.drop_while { |l| !l.include?('Nodes') } # Lines include 'Nodes' line
  every_line_after_nodes.drop(1) # Remove 'Nodes' line
end

p middle_lines
# => ["  * status of sub string 1\n", "  * status of sub string 2 \n"]
```

Or as a one-liner :

```
middle_lines = File.readlines('data.txt').take_while{|l| !l.include?('Jakarta')}.drop_while{|l| !l.include?('Nodes')}.drop(1)
```

Note : if `Nodes` isn't found, an empty Array will be returned. If `Jakarta` isn't found, every line after `Nodes` will be returned.
If you want an empty Array in both cases, you can use this :

```
module Enumerable
  def lines_after(substring)
    drop_while{|l| !l.include?(substring)}.drop(1)
  end

  def lines_before(substring)
    reverse.lines_after(substring).reverse
  end
end
```

Use it with :

```
File.readlines('data.txt').lines_after("Nodes").lines_before("Jakarta") # or 
File.readlines('data.txt').lines_before("Jakarta").lines_after("Nodes")
```

Comment: Perfect use case for the [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/).

Comment: @Eric Thanks! It worked nice!!

Comment: @mudasobwa : Wow. Never heard of it. It includes both extremes, though. See `File.foreach('data.txt'){|line| puts line if line.include?('Nodes') .. line.include?('Jakarta')}`

Comment: Your solution nevertheless has `.drop(1)` call :)

Comment: Yes. Except with `reverse + drop(1) + reverse`, I don't know how to drop the last element.

Comment: May I ask what’s wrong with `drop_while(!nodes).take_while(!jakarta)[1..-1]`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Could you please stop finding simple answers to my supposedly complex questions? ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil Roger that! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
λ = ->(items) { puts "Items are: #{items}" }

input.scan(/(?<=\A|\n).*?(?=\n- |\z)/m).each do |e|
  head, *rest = e.split(/\n+/)
  λ.(rest) unless rest.empty?
end

#⇒ Items are: [
#    "  * status of sub string 1",
#    "  * status of sub string 2 "
# ]
```

Here we declare the `lambda` to handle subitems. In the example above it just spits them out, but it might provide a sophisticated handler as well.

Then we split items and iterate split, as soon as split part contains subitems, the `lambda` is being called on the result.