# Find all elements in an array between two elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is there any method to get the elements in an array between two values?

Example:

```
arr = ["abc", "AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car", "kiss"]

## After some operation..
arr # =>  ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
```

How do I get the elements that are between `"AGC"` and `"car"` in a **new** array?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your attempt to solve this.  Without evidence of your effort it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Are the values in the array always ordered consistently?

Comment: Can `arr` contain duplicates? If so, what should be returned if `arr = ['abc', 'AGC', 'xxx', 'car', 'yyy', 'car', 'kiss']`?

Answer (score 6):

You could use Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/):

```
def extract(arr, first, last)
  return nil unless ([first, last]-arr).empty? && arr.index(first) <= arr.index(last)
  arr.select { |s| s==first..s==last ? true : false }
end

arr = ["abc", "AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car", "kiss"]

extract(arr, 'AGC', 'car')
  #=> ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
extract(arr, 'car', 'car')
  #=> ["car"] 
extract(arr, 'AGC', 'dog')
  #=> nil 
extract(arr, 'car', 'AGC')
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Also `!!(s=="AGC"..s=="car")` to get a little more intense.

Comment: @tadman, I didn't know that would work. I made an edit. Thanks. (Readers: I formerly had `s==first..s==last ? true : false` in the block.)

Comment: @tadman, on reflection I decided to roll back to what I had originally as I think it might be easier to understand by readers unfamiliar with the flip-flop operator.

Comment: `something ? true : false` is usually perfectly useless and redundant, but it's needed here to avoid an `ArgumentError`. I'd say that Stefan's comment with extra parens would be the most readable variation : `true if (s == first) .. (s == last)`

Comment: Cary, you are everywhere! I stumble upon your answers once per day at least :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're confident they're both present then you should be able to do this:

```
a = ["abc", "AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car", "kiss"]

a[(a.index('abc')+1)..a.index('car')]
# => ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
```

Comment: I had the same solution, but using a comma `a[a.index("abc") + 1,a.index("car")]`

Comment: @philipyoo That only works if `abc` is in position `0`. Try it on `xxx`. The second argument is the length if in `a,b` form. Subtle, but important.

Comment: ahh, nice didn't know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#drop_while`/`Array#take_while`. Note that this leads to one-off, hence the need for push at the end:

```
things = ['abc', 'AGC', 'xxx', 'tcv', 'car', 'kiss']

things.
  drop_while { |thingy| thingy != 'AGC' }.
  take_while { |thingy| thingy != 'car' }.
  push('car')
    # => ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
```

Alternatively:

```
things.
  slice_before { |thingy| thingy == 'AGC' }.to_a.last.
  slice_after { |thingy| thingy == 'car' }.first
    # => ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
```

Comment: If I remove `'car'` from `things`, it returns `["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "kiss", "car"]` and if `things = ['abc', 'car', 'xxx', 'tcv', 'AGC', 'kiss']` it returns `["AGC", "kiss", "car"]`. The OP may have implied `things` contains `'AGC'` and `'car'`, in that order, but it would be prudent to deal with bad data. If does read well and is efficient, however, deserving of an up arrow.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, if one of the two is not in the array, it is questionable what it means to take the elements **between** the two.  As for if they are swapped, you are correct. This assumes you know the order. Though I can use `#slice_between` to fix it, but it gets uglier.

Comment: You could preface with a simple data check, which would be easiest to show by wrapping it in a method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, [ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC) would be disappointed. Such checks make it no longer one-linery. xd

Comment: With two [`reverse`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44066019/6419007), it's possible to replace `take_while` by `drop_while` : with incorrect arguments, the method returns an empty array.

Comment: I get the feeling that `take_while` and `drop_while` should have an optional `exclusive` flag.

Comment: @Stefan, that would be nice. Though it's not clear what should happen when the *"border"* is more than one element. For example, should `[true, false, false].take_while(inclusive: true, &:itself)` return `[true, false]` or `[true, false, false]`. `take_until` and `drop_until` would be a good addition too.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `inclusive: true` is not an actual optional argument for `take_while`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it's not. It was just a suggestion that it would be nice to have it to resolve one-off issues like this one and I just expanded towards that it would be unclear how it should behave. Check Stefan's comment two comments above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of @ndn's answer, with 2 `reverse`s:

```
def extract(arr, first, last)
  arr.reverse.drop_while{ |x| x != last }.reverse.drop_while{ |x| x != first }
end

arr = %w[abc AGC xxx tcv car kiss]

p extract(arr, 'AGC', 'car')
#=> ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
p extract(arr, 'car', 'car')
#=> ["car"]
p extract(arr, 'AGC', 'dog')
#=> []
p extract(arr, 'car', 'AGC')
#=> []
```

The advantage of using 2 `drop_while`s is that no extra `push` or `drop` is needed, and if `first` and `last` aren't present or well ordered, the method returns an empty array.

Here's a related question : ["Ruby split lines from files while iterating each line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138915/ruby-split-lines-from-files-while-iterating-each-line/41140623)

Comment: Nice. Actually if you replace the `x != last`/`x != first` with `![first, last].include? x` you can also handle @Cary's concern (what to do if you don't know which value is first).

Comment: @ndn. Thanks. You'd need some more logic though, to make sure you don't use the same boundary twice. `extract(%w(a b c d e f g a), 'a', 'x')` should return `nil` or an empty array.

Comment: I'm a bit iffy that it should return `nil` or `[]`. It doesn't sound any more correct than anything else. But you have a point that it will not behave correctly for `extract(%w(a b x a), 'a', 'x')`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another silly way.

Assuming that the elements are all strings and a certain character, say `"@"`, is not included,

```
arr.join("@")[/(?<=@)AGC@.+@car(?=@)/].split("@")
# => ["AGC", "xxx", "tcv", "car"]
```